# How to handle Column overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I created a simple web app with Flutter.
The app layout is divided in two vertically zones: on the left there is a small top-bottom menu, on the right there is the main content inside a DataTable.

I wrapped the DataTable inside a SingleChildScrollView and everything worked fine.
The left side, on the other hand, keeps giving me a vertical overflow.

The tree on the left side is as follows:

```
Row(
  children: [
        //Left side menu
        Flexible(
           Container(
             Column()
           ), //Container
        ), //Flexible

        //Right side 
        Flexible(...),
 ],
), //Row
```

Obviously it is a very simplified version.

I've tried to insert a SingleChildScrollView in almost all places (Column, Container, Flexible), but it doesn't work and it always returns the error.

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 174 pixels on the bottom.

Any solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to use `MediaQuery` to get current height and width of the web window. Then spilt the available width in the ratio of 2:7 maybe? You can play around with the ratio.

Now, lets keep the body of `Scaffold` to be `Container` with width as `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and height as ... `.height`. Now `Row` with childrens be 2 Expanded widgets with `flex 2` and `flex 7` respectively. Now we have to portion in the screen in the ratio 2:7.

On the left side, as you said, you need a menu, let it be

```
Expanded(
 flex:2,
  child: Column())
```

And on the other side be-

```
Expanded(
  flex:7,
  child: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView() ///then add your stuff for scrolling purposes.
  )
)
```

learn more about `MediaQuery` [here](https://youtu.be/pxFPA8wdwKE)

learn more about `Expanded` [here](https://youtu.be/ruqMR5htic4)